# Can I install more than one version of microsoft office in my old laptop?

Tags: microsoft-office

My laptop is running XP SP3 which I bought 5 years ogo. 
I have right clicked "My Computer" to find its hardware specification:
P4-CPU 3Ghz, 2GB RAM, 40GB HDD, XP SP3, Microsoft Windows

It has MS office 2002 installed and I have been using MS Office 2002 to do some calculation and typing stuff, like sum of inventory cost, copying some useful news from Google News.
Until recently, I found that my laptop's MS office version might be too old to recognize an external excel file of MS Office 2010, because the laptop's MS Excel told me the new Excel file could not be opened.

So, I am going to spend a few hundred dollars to buy a genuine copy of MS Office 2010 (Some guy of the PC store nearby told me the price). But, before I do it, I would like to ask if it is OK to install another MS Office in my laptop.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are installing a newer version of Office, you will be asked if you wish to either:

a) Upgrade the existing Office install, or

b) Install the newer version of Office without affecting the older one

Either way, your document associations will be affected, so you will need to launch the older version of Office, then open older documents as needed, rather than having things open in the older version automatically.

If you have existing shortcuts in Quick Launch, on your desktop, in your start menu etc. etc. you will need to double check what version of the office apps they launch after the newer version is installed.

There's no need to use a different drive as suggested Reece Jeffery's answer.

Answer (score -4):

It will overwrite the files that are currently on it. However, if you install it onto another disk, such as a D:\ (if you have separate disks)it should be fine. I do believe that Office 2010 supports file of 1997-2003 versions of office. I am running Office16, and have opened 1 2003 file.

Comment: Did you do some research to verify your answer? If so, please provide some source links.